# How will Static behave here in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

I have an asp.net application with c# language. I have a common class which maintain the constants and static variables and fields. I also have a login page. If the user logs in successful I set IsLoggedInSuccessfull as a static boolean variable in common class.

My question is: Will this only work for a specific user session or for overall application ?

**Edited:**
Based on some answers I got another question here.

let say i am using the Static method as `Authenticate(User objUser)`. intention is to call this method when user clicked log in button. where on login button I am let say prepare the User object with certain parameters required for login, then passing to this method. what would be the impact there? let say I have single server for now (no server farm or garden). then there will be the single application level method  to authenticate the user, right? and say 10000 user are going to logging in to this site/application then how authenticate() method comes in behaves ? will CLR  automatically manage threading there ?

Comment: It will work for overall application.

Comment: Updated my post in response to you 2nd question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are at the application level, so it's shared across sessions.

So your situation:

> If the user logs in successful I set
>   IsLoggedInSuccessfull as a static
>   boolean variable in common class.

Would mean that now, for **every user** logging into the web application, if you check the variable `IsLoggedInSuccessfull`, the value would be true. So you probably want to keep this variable as a session variable, not a static variable.

Also keep in mind that if you have a web farm, each server has an instance of your web application running on it - meaning that on each application instance, the static variables can potentially have different values (if you are not careful). Same principle for web gardens...

**Regarding your second question:**
CLR does not manage thread safety - you need to take care of it yourself. That being said, if the static method does not use any global static variables in itself, and if the `User` instance you pass into the static method is unique, you should be safe. If the `User` instance is **not** unique, make sure to put thread safety code in the appropriate places in the `User` class.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful for me for variables. but please review question again that i have edited.

Answer (score 1):

A static class will maintain the value.

But, using `Session` instead is much better because it is more intuitive in a web application and is a widely used practice.

Here is a good article on the subject:

[Managing Your Static Data in ASP.NET](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Managing-Your-Static-Data-in-ASPNET/)

Comment: Why won't it maintain value? As soon as application is not restarted, the value should be available to all threads using it.

Comment: umm... not true. You could potentially slow down your web server, or overburden the server memory by putting everything (for instance, dozens database calls to generate global lookups, load common templates, etc.) into Session.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making the change to a static class it will be for the *specific instance* of the overall application.

If you are running multiple instances that are load balanced, it will only be set in one of them.

Comment: Actually, it will be set in **each** of them. However, the values may not be the same. If an instance variable, these will be different objects on each application instance.

Comment: Thanks code4life. As I understand it, the instance of the application that is dealing with the request will set its static variable. So, if two instances are running (instance1 and instance2), and a single request comes in and forwarded to instance1, only instance1's static variable is changed? But it's possible for another request to be dealt with by instance2, so the instance2's static variable is changed. Each can be set, but only one will be changed per request, because instance1 and instance2 don't share requests?

Comment: if you use sticky sessions, then it's guaranteed that the user will not bounce between the two application instances. If you're using load balanced, then the request sent from the user is not guaranteed to always go to the same server. This can result in erratic behavior and errors from the back end, unless your design accomodates for the load balanced behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable will be shared across application instance, meaning that it is the same variable for every request (user), while you are running single instance app.
For user specific information use `session` object.